# How does ArcGIS calculate Live Traffic in a network dataset?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, network-analyst, traffic

I create a network analyst service in ArcGIS 10.2 with live traffic.  The traffic is classified into four classes (stop and go, slow, moderate and free flow). I know that when the service uses historical traffic the traffic calculate using free flow and travel speed.  In Live traffic I only have travel speed but the result of traffic in map shows the four classes.  How the service calculate and show live traffic in my service?

Comment: Wouldn't it be proportional to current speed divided by max speed on that vertex?

Comment: I don't think so .I try to find a relation between current speed and max speed. I think the length of the segments are another parameter  to calculate the proportion . I set the max speed to 80 kmph and current speed of segments to 80 kmph . There are some differences between segments . some of   segments show slow traffic and some show free flow and ... .I think it depends of the length of segments . because segements with same length have same traffic .I don't sure . If you sure please understand me . Thanks @JasonScheirer